# Example for a set that is open connected but not path connected in an arbitrary topological space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, path-connected

I know the result that in $R^n$ any open connected set is path connected. But I guess in general the result is not true in an arbitrary topological space.

Can anyone give an example showing this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: As a subset of itself, the topologist's sine curve is open, connected, but not path connected: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve

Answer (score 2):

Any space $X$ that is connected, but not path-connected is a trivial example: $X$ is open in itself..